# Setting an Image onto ImageView via Java on a separate Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a simple app that merely takes in a few inputs via radio buttons, seek bar progress and checkboxes, then returns a screen detailing whether the user likes cats or dogs.

So far, I've confirmed that everything runs perfectly up till the point where I try to `setImageDrawable()` in Activity2. I've managed to get the TextView to show the correct line of text, i.e.: YOU LIKE DOGS, signifying that the intent and `putExtra()` bit of the code is working just fine.

The only problem is this line of code right here, (commenting it out makes the app work just fine)

```
image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.meceline));
```

I've triple checked to make sure that I've

1) Placed the image into the layout folder of Android Studio

2) The image is completely lowercase letters

3) The name is spelt correctly in the Java file.

I've tried the exact same code with the exact same image in another separate project where I set an Image onto an ImageView in the MainActivity and that works just fine. The only difference is now, I'm setting an Image onto Activity2 that I get to from MainActivity.

The entire code is down below, and thanks in advance for anyone who can help me out.

### Edit:

This was the error.

```
09-09 10:57:05.479  24786-24786/com.example.cartermah.dogorcat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:636)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:365)
            at com.example.cartermah.dogorcat.activity2.onCreate(activity2.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

OH! I just realised and googled what the error means. It just means that the image i tried to load was too large. Which now leaves me with another problem. I could just use a smaller, lower resolution image, but would there be no way to stick with the current image that I want to use?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup radgroup1;
    private RadioButton radbutton1;
    private RadioGroup radgroup2;
    private RadioButton radbutton2;
    private Button button1;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    public int Dog;
    public int Cat;
    private CheckBox check1;
    private CheckBox check2;
    private int seekbarcheck;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radgroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radgroup1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        radgroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.droolgroup);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        Dog = 0;
        Cat = 0;
        check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dogbox);
        check2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.catbox);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int chosen1 = radgroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radbutton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(chosen1);

                if (radbutton1.getText().equals("Whiskers")) {

                    Dog = Dog + 1;


                } else if (radbutton1.getText().equals("Tails")) {


                    Cat = Cat + 1;
                }


                seekbarcheck = seekbar.getProgress();


                if (seekbarcheck > 5) {
                    Dog = Dog + 1;
                } else {
                    Cat = Cat + 1;
                }


                if (check1.isChecked()) {
                    Dog = Dog + 1;
                }

                if (check2.isChecked()) {
                    Cat = Cat + 1;
                }


                int chosen2 = radgroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                radbutton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(chosen2);

                if (radbutton2.getText().equals("YES")) {
                    Dog = Dog + 1;
                }
                if (radbutton2.getText().equals("NO")) {
                    Cat = Cat + 1;
                }


                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);

                if (Dog > Cat) {
                    intent1.putExtra("result", 1);
                } else if (Cat > Dog) {
                    intent1.putExtra("result", 2);
                } else if (Dog == Cat) {
                    intent1.putExtra("result", 3);
                }


                startActivity(intent1);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
public class activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView text1;
    private ImageView image2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textresult);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.boo123);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


        if (bundle != null) {

            int result = bundle.getInt("result");

            if (result == 1) {
                text1.setText("YOU LIKE DOGS");
                image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.meceline));
            } else if (result == 2) {
                text1.setText("YOU LIKE CATS");
                image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pau));
            } else if (result == 3) {
                text1.setText("Cheese?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: 1) Placed the image into the layout folder of Android Studio
Images have to into the drawable folder

Comment: do you have error just for `image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.meceline));` or also for `image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pau));` ?
Is that a runtime error or a build error?

Comment: for me your code looks ok. you didn-t tell us what your problem is: null pointer exception or the image is not updated at all, showing a wrong content, .....  I asssume you have a null pointer exception: have you also "triple-checked" that R.id.boo123 corresponds to the image control in your layoutfile  `activity_main2.xml`?

Comment: Yep, just checked again to make sure but R.id.boo123 is pointing to the correct (and only) ImageView in activity_main2.xml.  - @k3b

I click on the error message and it links me to just the 

image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.meceline));

but commenting that line of code out and trying to get the second image to pop out doesn't work either. -@Stefano

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
image2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.meceline));
```

try this

```
image2.setImageDrawable(this.getDrawable(R.drawable.meceline));
```

Comment: Just tried it and it still doesn't work. It still just crashes. I've edited in the error message above. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You pass  intent1.putExtra("result", 1);

and in activity2 you are getting value in bundle
but remember you haven't pass bundle you are sending putExtra in key "result".

So do one thing in your second activity put this code
sure this will help you

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int result = mIntent.getIntExtra("result", 0);
```

And please do not use bundle in activity2. 
try this and feel free to ask anything. :)

here i am writing full code of your activity2.
Replace this code ..

```
public class activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView text1;
private ImageView image2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textresult);
image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.boo123);

Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int result = mIntent.getIntExtra("result", 0);

if (result == 1) {
text1.setText("YOU LIKE DOGS");
image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.meceline);
} else if (result == 2) {
text1.setText("YOU LIKE CATS");
 image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pau));
} else if (result == 3) {
text1.setText("Cheese?");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: and also use image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.meceline); etc. to set  images from drawable..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. Still kinda new to all of this. I've tried testing it out and the activity does manage to get the data in the bundle because the textView in activity2 displays correctly with the right text, but only the image doesn't show. 

Also, I just tried using image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.meceline); but it didn't work